# Is it possible to cast from vector parent* to vector child* in a function without using templates

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, vector, reinterpret-cast

While working on a data import system I decided to store a lot of objects deriving from one class in a vector of pointers to the parent class. And then I would like to have a function that returns a vector of any type of child pointers (using paramaters that let me know what kind of child it is).

I managed to realize a similar and simplified code here, but it uses templates and casts and I feel like only casts could be enough. However the compiler does not want to do any cast from vector A*  to vector B*.

EDIT: In the real code there are many child classes, not only B, so replacing the template by B is not an option, sorry for not being precise enough.

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A
{
  public:

    int attr;

    A(): attr(1) {}
};

class B : public A
{
  public:

    B(): A() {attr = 2;}
};

template <typename O>
vector<O*> bees(vector<A*> vecA)
{
    auto vecO = vector<O*>();

    for (auto it = vecA.begin(); it != vecA.end(); it++)
    {
        if ((*it)->attr == 2)
        {
            vecO.push_back(reinterpret_cast<O*>(*it));
        }
    }

    return vecO;
}

int main()
{
    auto vecA = vector<A*>();

    vecA.push_back(new A());
    vecA.push_back(new B());
    vecA.push_back(new B());

    vector<B*> vecB = bees<B>(vecA);
}
```

So my question is : Is it possible to have a code do the same effect without using templates ? And if not does the compiler generate specific code with this one ? Knowing there would be theorically no difference in runtime no matter the  template.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using a `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: I am using reinterpret cast because it I do not cast it just doesn't compile, and it feels to me like it is the most adequate here knowing I do not need to do any changes on the object.

Comment: This smells. `std::vector` of raw pointers can be justified, but here it's not. You have UB because you cast a pointer to `A` to a pointer to `B`. And you unnecessarily copy `vecA` when calling `bees` because you don't use a reference. This strongly feels like you have an XY problem.

Comment: The general idea of a common base class is that it defines an interface that all the derived classes adhere to. Whenever you feel the need to store the type of the derived class (`attr`) so you can treat them *differently*, this is a sign of them *not* having the same interface. Then they should likely not have a common base class either. You are just seeing one symptom of this problem, and "fixing" this part treats the symptom not the disease.

Comment: If the base class is polymorphic (i.e. with at least one virtual member function) you can use `dynamic_cast` to check if an `A*` actually points to an `O`, and push the result into the vector. If you want your code to work for ANY class derived from `A`, it either needs to be a template or there needs to be an explicit overload for EVERY derived class. It is also necessary for the caller to supply information so the compiler can work out the type being converted to - with an overloaded function, one way is to provide an extra argument that supplies type information.

Comment: Your design is broken (if you know you can have only Bs in a vector of As, why not make it a vector of Bs in the first place?) and your implementation is broken too (reinterpret_cast is never a correct way to navigate a class hierarchy). And now it seems you want to break it even more. Perhaps ask a question about the design, it's more important than implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a function that can return vector of any type of child pointer so i believe template is needed to specify child type but certain things like reinterpret_cast etc. is not needed and here is sample implementation :

```
class A
{
  public:

    int attr;

    A(): attr(1) {}
    virtual ~A() {};
};

class B : public A
{
  public:

    B(): A() {attr = 2;}

};
template<typename T>
vector<T*> bees(const vector<A*> &vecA)
{
    vector<T*> vec;

    for (auto it = vecA.begin(); it != vecA.end(); it++)
    {
        T* ptr = dynamic_cast<T*>(*it);
        if(ptr != nullptr)
        {
          vec.push_back(*it);
        }
    }

    return vec;
}
```

We are using dynamic_cast because we are downcasting parent type to child type.Also for dynamic_cast to work we need virtual destructor/virtual function as it require RTTI

Comment: Although I doubt that OP asks the right question, I also doubt that this is an answer to his or her question. The question was to find a solution *without* using a template function.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi But in some way you have to specify what child type vector you want to create.There can be other approaches also like using if/else and then typecasting based on that but template seems more elegant

Comment: Your code is a step in the right direction to say the least. And, yes, I like templates. It's just not what OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance and polymorphy are supposed to hide away different child types, so the rest of your code doesn't have to worry about specific types.

Casting objects to specific types is very likely not the right approach to whatever you're trying to do. Let the types decide how they are used and what they do, not the outside world.

If you want to filter a vector to get only objects with specific properties, you shouldn't look at their types, you should ask them if they have the properties you are looking for:

```
void FilterA(const std::vector<A>& source, std::vector<A>& destination, std::function<bool(const A&)> filter) {
    std::copy_if(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(destination), filter);
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
std::vector<A> filteredVecA;
FilterA(vecA, filteredVecA, [](const A& a){return a.HasSomePropertyYouCareAbout();});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider moving the type checking inside the hierarchy (this uses templates, but no casts):

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A(); // you _are_ in a hierarchy of objects

    template<typename T>
    virtual T* as() const { return nullptr; }
};

template<typename X>
class Convertible: public A {

    template<typename T>
    virtual T* as() const {
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<X, T>)
            return this;
        else
            return nullptr;
    }
};

class B: public Convertible<B> {
};

template <typename O>
vector<O*> bees(vector<A*> vecA)
{
    auto vecO = vector<O*>();

    foreach (auto ptr: vecA)
    {
        auto ptrO = ptr->as<O>();
        if (ptrO)
            vecO.push_back(ptrO);
    }
    return vecO;
}
```

Some points:

OP's comment:

> I am using reinterpret cast because it I do not cast it just doesn't compile, and it feels to me like it is the most adequate here knowing I do not need to do any changes on the object.

`dynamic_cast` is usually a symptom of an insufficiently designed class hierarchy. Whenever you think "I can solve this with dynamic_cast" consider adding code to your class hierarchy instead.